# how can i set a hadoop multinode cluster in my laptop?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, vmware-player

Am using CHD3 on centos 5.6 in vmware virtual machine and am facing so many problems while configuring the multinode cluster.
Can anybody provide complete steps to configure multinode cluster??

Answer (score 0):

Configuring a distributed cluster by yourself is a bit of a headache, can be done but it won't worth it if you're just testing and doing some research.

Since you're using Cloudera, you should take a look at Cloudera Manager, which automates the installation and management of Hadoop clusters and should play nice with VMs as well (as long as you have some serious RAM): 
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-manager/v4-8-2/Cloudera-Manager-Introduction/cmi_primer.html

This is the installation guide:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-manager/v4-8-2/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide.html